# unable to filter some numerical values (Pandas, python)

Tags: python, pandas, filter

I have a df which i have trouble filtering some specific value (0.112, 0.123, etc.). I've tried filtering other random values(0.155, .0113, 0.145, etc) and they were found. I've tried using apply(pd.to_numeric), but still having the same issue.

Is this a float/integer issue i need to  rectifier when loading the cvs file? And i've double checked that the values i have trouble filtering are indeed in the csv file.

code used

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df= pd.read_csv("C:/Users/data.csv")
df= df.apply(pd.to_numeric)

df= df.loc[df['columnA'] == 0.112]
```

Regards
Many thanks

{'columnA': {0: 0.542,
1: 0.191,
2: 0.191,
3: 0.191,
4: 0.191,
5: 0.191,
6: 0.191,
7: 0.192,
8: 0.192,
9: 0.091}

Comment: without data.csv or a sample of it we can't help you

Comment: Please add to your question the result of `df.head(10).to_dict()`

Comment: i'd love to provide the csv file, however, there's no attach file option... and using a sample would probably not solve the issue, as it's probably an issue with the csv format.

Comment: @ Ben.T, i've added the result as you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

These values could have been truncated by pandas - so the value could actually be 0.112156327 but its showing you only 0.112

Comment: the csv was created from a df which i've specifically rounded to 3.  df['columnA'].round(3)